# ActiveMQ HTTP Jakarta

Tags: activemq-classic, jakarta-migration

I’m using ActiveMQ "Classic" 5.18.1 with Spring 6 and the Jakarta namespace. I’m using `activemq-client-jakarta` for TCP connections, but now I’m facing a new problem. I need to deal with http, but no activemq-http-jakarta jar is provided.

Are there any plans to create an `activemq-http-jakarta` jar as was done for `activemq-client`?

`ActiveMQConnectionFactory` is coming from `activemq-client-jakarta`.

Here is the log I'm getting when I try to send message over `https` protocol:

```
Caused by: jakarta.jms.JMSException: Transport scheme NOT recognized: [https]
    at org.apache.activemq.util.JMSExceptionSupport.create(JMSExceptionSupport.java:91)
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection.syncSendPacket(ActiveMQConnection.java:1483)
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection.ensureConnectionInfoSent(ActiveMQConnection.java:1548)
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection.createSession(ActiveMQConnection.java:370)
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.executeLocal(JmsTemplate.java:950)
    ... 170 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Transport scheme NOT recognized: [https]
    at org.apache.activemq.util.IOExceptionSupport.create(IOExceptionSupport.java:30)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportFactory.findTransportFactory(TransportFactory.java:185)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportFactory.compositeConnect(TransportFactory.java:90)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.failover.FailoverTransport.doReconnect(FailoverTransport.java:1020)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.failover.FailoverTransport$2.iterate(FailoverTransport.java:151)
    at org.apache.activemq.thread.PooledTaskRunner.runTask(PooledTaskRunner.java:133)
    at org.apache.activemq.thread.PooledTaskRunner$1.run(PooledTaskRunner.java:48)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    ... 1 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Could not find factory class for resource: META-INF/services/org/apache/activemq/transport/https
    at org.apache.activemq.util.FactoryFinder$StandaloneObjectFactory.loadProperties(FactoryFinder.java:104)
    at org.apache.activemq.util.FactoryFinder$StandaloneObjectFactory.create(FactoryFinder.java:61)
    at org.apache.activemq.util.FactoryFinder.newInstance(FactoryFinder.java:154)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportFactory.findTransportFactory(TransportFactory.java:182)
    ... 8 common frames omitted
```

Comment: i’m using activemqconnectionfactory with http or https protocol. But in log i got no http(s) scheme.

Comment: @JustinBertram see EDIT1 ;)

Comment: No, that’s the first thing i do but in my war i have now activemq-client that i don’t want:( perhaps i just need to exclude it? But will other things not work?

Comment: Ok i will try tomorrow. And i let you know if it work

Comment: Full Jakarta support for the rest of the ActiveMQ modules is planned for 5.19.x. Status of the PR can be monitored here:
https://github.com/apache/activemq/pull/996

Comment: @MattPavlovich What is the tentative release date for 5.19.x? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @SoumyadipDas the release vote should happen in the next 1-2 weeks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell no changes are required to the `activemq-http` jar for it to work with the `activemq-client-jakarta` jar so that you can use the `http` or `https` URL schemes. You just need to have both jars on the classpath of your application which, given the stack-trace you pasted, is clearly not the case.

Comment: when i'm adding the activemq-http jar as maven dependency, i get many other activemq jar by transitivity like activemq-client/activemq-spring/activemq-jms-pool/activemq-mqtt/activemq-jms-pool/activemq-broker, i have exclude all of them and my https connection seems to work. i just think that because maven get activemq-client by transitivity i need to change activemq-http to jakarta too! finally not! thanks

Comment: FYI-- This comment should be updated to note that activemq-http 5.18.1 won't work with activemq-client-jakarta until 5.19.0 with full Jakarta support

Comment: What changes are being made to the `activemq-http` module for Jakarta support from the client's perspective? I realize that there are some uses of `javax` in the module, but they look related specifically to the broker, not the client. Also, unless I misunderstood the OP everything appears to be working now that they classpath issue is sorted.

Comment: activemq-http contains both the client and server bits. It has transitive dependencies, such as spring, jetty, activemq-pool, etc. No guarantee you can happy path client-only without having a transitive reference problem.

Comment: The transitive dependencies are all for the server bits, right? A remote JMS client using `https` (i.e. `org.apache.activemq.transport.https.HttpsTransportFactory`) or `http` (i.e. `org.apache.activemq.transport.http.HttpTransportFactory`) shouldn't care about all those transitive dependencies so it should be safe from anything that uses `javax`/`jakarta`.